# To implement masking based on position of characters in string on column

Tags: python, pandas, masking

I want to implement masking based on position, we will give lower and upper bound for string in column.

Let me explain with an example. I am trying below code

```
columnname = "phonenumber"

column_dataset1[columnname] = column_dataset1[columnname][2:] + "****" + column_dataset1[columnname][:4]
print(column_dataset1)
```

This is the file I am using

```
sno,Name,Type 1,Type 2,phonenumber
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,987654321256464684846646464611631646466464
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,98765432121314564645663114646464666432016364
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,9876543212
```

I want output as below:

```
sno,Name,Type 1,Type 2,phonenumber
    1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,9876****1256464684846646464611631646466464
    2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,9876****121314564645663114646464666432016364
    3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,9876****12
```

Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: I which line of your code you are getting the error?

Comment: to_del = [i for i,v in enumerate(counts) if (float(v)/df.shape[0]*100) < 1] 
At this line i am getting error

Comment: what do you want to achieve

Comment: It seems that your `counts` object do not have __iter__() function, so you can't iterate over it. Try tu use `.to_numpy()` as mentioned in Error description

`to_del = [i for i,v in enumerate(counts.to_numpy()) if (float(v)/df.shape[0]*100) < 1]`

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this?